# How to create a principal based on an arbitrary http header?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using spring security to secure my application, but I can't understand how the principal is actually created.

On the web I can only find references about how to provide a custom AuthenticationProvider but problem is that the principal will always be empty, this is because I need to construct it based on an http header, namely "MY_AUTH_HEADER".

This header contains data that I have to use in conjuction with a db.

So, starting by:

```
public class MedMadAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    authentication.getName(); //how can I create an "Authentication" object based on headers?
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false; //How can I specify my own auth class?
}
}
```

What do I have to define to be *before* this filter and create the Authentication object starting from headers?

Answer (score 0):

The `Authentication` object gets extracted in an `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

You can create a custom `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` that creates an `Authentication` object based on information in your custom header.

In the example below, the `CustomAuthenticationFilter` will be invoked on requests to "/login".
It will create a custom `Authentication` object, namely `CustomAuthenticationToken`, based on the value in the header MY_AUTH_HEADER.

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager manager) {
        super("/login");
        setAuthenticationManager(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String authToken = request.getHeader("MY_AUTH_HEADER");

        CustomAuthenticationToken authentication = new CustomAuthenticationToken(authToken);

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authentication);
    }
}
```

You can then add the custom filter to the security chain.

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .addFilterAt(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Depending on your authentication mechanism, you may be able to reuse an existing `Authentication`, such as `BearerTokenAuthenticationToken` or `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

If you need to create a custom `Authentication` object, here is an example.

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken {

    private String token;

    public CustomAuthenticationToken(String token) {
        super(Collections.emptyList());

        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return this.token;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return this.token;
    }
}
```

If you are using a custom `Authentication` object, then you can create a custom `AuthenticationProvider` to support your custom `Authentication`, as shown below.
This is not necessary if you are using an existing `Authentication` (e.g `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`) as there is already an `AuthenticationProvider` that supports it.

```java
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if ("secret".equals(authentication.getCredentials())) {
            return authentication;
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Header did not match expected value");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return CustomAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

[This section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-abstractprocessingfilter) of the Spring Security reference documentation explains how all these components interact with one another.

Comment: Seems good but now it always give me 302 when authenticated :(

Comment: The default success handler will redirect users to the homepage, which is why the response is a 302. You can customize the success handler on your filter by using `setAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in this dsl and it seems very confusing to me....on what should I call the setAuthenticationSuccessHandler? There is a lot :( And I'm seeing that the successhandler interface does not provide the possibility to do not redirect

Comment: Ok solved for the successhandler but now I have another weird problem: would it be possible to attach this authenticator to the ant matchers of the spring security dsl? At the moment it only triggers for login but I'd like for it to be agnostic and let the user specify via the http configuration

Comment: There are a few ways to do that. One option is to add the path to the constructor of `CustomAuthenticationFilter`. Then the user can specify the path when they add the filter. Another option is to create a [custom DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#jc-custom-dsls).